# Datos duplicados consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mi base de datos *MySQL*

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
s.nombre_semestre as nombre_semestre, 
e.name as nombre_establecimiento, 
a.rut, 
a.nombres, 
a.apellidos, 
DATE_FORMAT(a.fecha_ingreso_practica, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_ingreso_practica

FROM form1_alumno a 
INNER JOIN servicio_de_salud_antofagasta f 
INNER JOIN semestres s on f.semestre_ano=s.id 
INNER JOIN establecimiento e on a.id_establecimiento=e.id n 

WHERE a.id_establecimiento = 19 
and a.semestre_ano = 2 
and a.id_formulario_1=f.id_formulario_1 
and a.estatus = 1
```

Si quito el campo **fecha_ingreso_practica** no me muestra los registros duplicados y con eso estaria bien, pero necesito el campo **fecha_ingreso_practica**

Lo que necesito es que la consulta pueda comparar el campo `a.fecha_ingreso_practica` entre los registros que se repiten y solo mantener el que tenga la fecha mas cercana y el resto no los muestre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces tienes que agrupar, prueba así:

```
SELECT  s.nombre_semestre as nombre_semestre, 
e.name as nombre_establecimiento, 
a.rut, 
a.nombres, 
a.apellidos, 
DATE_FORMAT(MAX(a.fecha_ingreso_practica), '%d-%m-%Y')
as fecha_ingreso_practica

FROM form1_alumno a 
INNER JOIN servicio_de_salud_antofagasta f 
INNER JOIN semestres s on f.semestre_ano=s.id 
INNER JOIN establecimiento e on a.id_establecimiento=e.id n 

WHERE a.id_establecimiento = 19 
and a.semestre_ano = 2 
and a.id_formulario_1=f.id_formulario_1 
and a.estatus = 1

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso era lo que necesitaba..

Comment: Una consulta, los numeros del 1 al 5 en el GROUP BY, que hacen en la consulta???

Comment: Agrupar por los primeros cinco campos que aparecen tras el `SELECT`

Comment: Entonces si tengo mas campos después del SELECT debo seguir agregando números ??   ej: GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;  o hay algún limite???

Comment: Lo habitual es que, si el resto de campos pertenecen al mismo registro, con que agrupes por la clave primaria es suficiente. Yo te los agrupé todos por tu `DISTINCT`